# How to use Xdebug to profile a single php file?

Tags: php, profiling, xdebug

I want to use Xdebug to profile a single php file. From [Xdebug documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler), it is said

> Profiling is enabled by setting the xdebug.profiler_enable setting to 1 in php.ini. This instructs Xdebug to start writing profiling information into the dump directory configured with the xdebug.profiler_output_dir directive.

I tried but Xdebug will generate so many profile logs. I have no testing environment but only could use production server. I want to know is there any way to set just testing one page?

Any suggestions to do this?

**---Update 02/11/2013---------------------------**

Finally I choose [facebook / xhprof](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof) as my production server profiler. I use xhprof_html everyday now. It save a lot of time and very easy to use, especially the Full Callgraph view.

Comment: So you have xdebug on production server. Nice, I always wanted one.

Comment: What's the problem of Xdebug on production server? I could disable it when I don't need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the trigger http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#profiler_enable_trigger and add it to your url. i.e. http://example.com/mypage.php?XDEBUG_PROFILE=1

Also, XHProf is preferred over XDebug when profiling on production: https://github.com/facebook/xhprof

Comment: Thanks for XHProf on production

Answer (score 2):

There is another option in the xdebug configuration that will do this: `xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger`. Set it to 1 and then open the URL you want to profile with a querystring suffix of `?XDEBUG_PROFILE`. It will then write a log just for that script.

Comment: If you want to profile single session in CLI use environment variable `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=session_name profiler_enable=1` instead.